# How To Hide Video Controls In IOS Latest Version(17+)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, shopify

Is there any way that I can hide the video controls on ios, I have added the video in the product gallery section in shopify, I have already tried few steps, but none of them have worked out.

1. Remove the controls from the video section of main-product.liquid, everywhere else as well, where the controls are mentioned.
2. Added the script in the theme.liquid file.

```
<script >
      var video = document.querySelector('#MainProduct-template--21546534895895__main');
      video.removeAttribute('controls');
  </script>
```

3. added the css in base.css file.

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display: none !important;
  opacity: 0; 
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
    display: none !important;
}
```

4. Added the id the video code and added the script in the theme.liquid.

```
{% if media.media_type == "video" %}
{{ media | media_tag: image_size: "720x", autoplay: true, loop: loop, preload: "none", id: myvideo, autoplay: true, height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
{% else %}

<script>
  document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('play', function() {
    this.controls = false;
  });
</script>
```

In android and windows it is working fine, but in iphone it is still showing the controls is there a way through which we can hide it.

This is the url where I have added the video in product gallery.

https://bolderglow.com/products/glowscape-drawing-kit

Thanks

Comment: If I remove the line `controls="controls"` from your `<video>` tag in the HTML, then I don't see the controls in Safari.

Comment: Hi @Kokodoko The issue is I have already removed controls from the code, but it is still showing, and I am not sure from where it is coming. That's why I have tried adding the javascript which is also not working

Comment: If I google for this problem, it seems that you need to adjust the shopify template for video and remove the controls manually: https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/removing-video-controls-in-product-studio-theme/td-p/1637707